# Find the closing price of stocks in last 90 days using python

Tags: python, excel, stock

Details of Case: There are 161 stocks in excel file, you have to find closing price for these stocks for last 90days

Download  files using following links : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1utGBygI2vcs0hYlnTpCA_i3Uo8VRj1lH?usp=sharing
File 1: List of Stocks case study : Symbol of stocks
File 2: Sample Output Format for one stock: This file has desired output format for one stock.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud try [pandas_datareader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readers/yahoo.html#module-pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily) package .
It will help you to find a data as you want.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data

symbol = 'INFY' # pass the symbol name
end = pd.datetime.now() # current date and time - can be changed as per requirement
start = end - pd.Timedelta(days=90) # ninety days before

df = data.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', start, end)

# get close price
close_price = df['Close']

# get last n close prices
n = 3
last_n_close_price = close_price.tail(n)

print("Last {} close prices:".format(n))
print(last_n_close_price)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).